# Operation not permitted on IsolatedStorageFileStream. when using MvvmCross file plugin

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1, mvvmcross

I have an instance of IMvxFileStore implementation for for Windows Phone injected into my service.

Let say I want to store settings in a file located at appsettings\userprofiles\profile1.txt

Using the file plugin, I first call the API **EnsureFolder** exists, passing in the full path to my profile settings file appsettings\userprofiles\profile1.txt to ensure that this folder has been created and does exist.

Just for sanity, I check to ensure that the folder has been created using the **FolderExist** API.  This always returns true atleast for now.

The code looks like this:

```
  private string GetStorageItemFileName(string filename)
        {
            Guard.ThrowIfNull(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BaseDirectory), Messages.RepositorBackingStoreIsNull);
            filename = _fileStore.PathCombine(BaseDirectory, filename); 

            _fileStore.EnsureFolderExists(filename);    
            if (_fileStore.FolderExists(filename))
            {
                // what do do????
            }

            return filename;
        }
```

However, when I attempt to write content to the file using **WriteToFile** API, passing in the file name returned from the method above and some string, as follows

```
 try
            {
                _fileStore.WriteFile(filename, content);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Logger.Error(ex);
            }
```

, I get the following exception:

> System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageException was caught
>   HResult=-2146233264   Message=Operation not permitted on
>   IsolatedStorageFileStream.   Source=mscorlib   StackTrace:
>          at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize,
>   IsolatedStorageFile isf)
>          at System.IO.IsolatedStorage.IsolatedStorageFileStream..ctor(String path,
>   FileMode mode, IsolatedStorageFile isf)
>          at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WindowsPhone.MvxIsolatedStorageFileStore.WriteFileCommon(String
>   path, Action`1 streamAction)
>          at Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.WindowsPhone.MvxIsolatedStorageFileStore.WriteFile(String
>   path, String contents)
>          at TrackuTransit.Core.Services.DataStore.StorageItemFileRepository.Put(String
>   filename, StorageItem data)   InnerException:

My dev environment is setup as follows:
- Surface Pro 3
- Visual Studio 2013 Community
- Windows Phone 8.1 SDK and Simulator
- MvvmCross 3.0.0.4.  (yes,, it is old and will be updated after MVP).

Before I go digging into the MvvmCross code base, anyone with ideas on what I could be doing wrong here?

Comment: At this point it's hard to tell since you are on such an old version.  I would try to get the project up to the latest and greatest as it may be taken care of already.  This will sting for you as you will need to change your PCL profile to 259 or something compatible.

Comment: Also make sure you don't have multiple threads accessing the isolated storage at the same time.  If you do you'll need to set the last parameter of the open file call to System.IO.FileShare.ReadWrite or whatever permission you need.

Comment: This is the answer I was hoping not to hear :) since upgrading the solution at this point (including 28 projects) will set me back for atleast a couple of days.  I doubt it a cross threading issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgraded the project to .NET 4.5 and also upgraded to MvvmCross 3.5.1 and still ran into the same problem.  Although I lost a couple of days due from the upgrade, I am glad it is over with.

The problem I am running into here has to do with the fact that I am calling

```
 _fileStore.EnsureFolderExists(filename);
```

and passing in the full path to the file.  Underneath the scenes, MvvmCross is calling

```
IsolatedStorageFile.CreateDirectory(filename);
```

which appears to be creating a directory with the same file name.  So passing in "images\image1.png" to the above API appears to create a directory or hold some IO resource related to "images\images.png".

When you attempt to write to file using

```
_fileStore.WriteFile(filename, content);
```

MvvmCross is attempting to create a file stream using

```
var fileStream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream(path, FileMode.Create, isf))
```

and the exception is thrown right here.

Fix is to ensure you are passing to IMvxFileStore.EnsureFolderExists API just the folder in question.  In this case it is "images".  Then you pass to IMvxFileStore.WriteFile the relative path to the file including the file name such as "images\image1.png" and you are good to go.

Fixed code looks like this:

```
private string GetStorageItemFileName(string filename)
        {
            Guard.ThrowIfNull(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(BaseDirectory), Messages.RepositorBackingStoreIsNull);
            filename = _fileStore.PathCombine(BaseDirectory, filename); 

           // assumption is that filename does not contain directory information
            _fileStore.EnsureFolderExists(BaseDirectory);    

            return filename;
        }
```