# Windows Phone app updated to .NET 4.5 and MvvmCross 3.5.1 causes crash

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, mvvmcross, portable-class-library

I have an Windows Phone 8 application that was working fine in .NET 4 and MvvmCross 3.0.0.4.  To solve the problem reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30966791/mvvmcross-file-plugin-exception-when-writing-to-file), I upgraded the solution to .NET 4.5 and MvvmCross 3.5.1.

Now when I launch the application it attempts to load and the just crashes but there are no logs written to the Console.  I have enabled CLR Exceptions but no exception is already been logged to the Console.

My dev environment is Surface Pro 3, and Visual Studio 2013 Community.

Anyone run into a similar problem upgrading their projects?

Comment: Check your class for loadstate, and other help class, they have change in the new version

Comment: @Juan, could you please be more specific?  What is load state and what other help class are you referring to?

Comment: This are a set of classes which are added to the project by visual studio to help you manage some things like capture parameters sent from page to page. You cN create a blank project and then add a blank page and visual studio will add this files. This same behavior from visual studio was available in version 8 but the content of this added files is different.

Answer (score 1):

I just ended up creating a new working Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1 project and migrated all of my files from the failing project to the new one.

So far so good,

Comment: Be aware of the difference between silverlight or not, just to double check here is a link https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn655124(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with this change: https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross/pull/867

Comment: @Juan, here original app was a Silverlight application.  I just ended up creating a new non-silverlight version.